# linearlayout height matching other linearLayout

Tags: android, layout, android-fragments

how can i make sure my text behind the checkbox is the same height as the check box and image?

I don't want to use any DIP or anything, as i want it to run on multiple devices. But if there is no other way so be it.
Here is an example of what it is now

see Image here :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/udhzc.png]

XML Code :

```
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/storeParent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/storetest"
            android:layout_width="177dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/storesingleStore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/storesettings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Please note that i add margins programmatically .

```
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new   LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.topMargin=2;
```

And that this is a fragment.

Comment: use layout weight and make the height as 0dp

Comment: that works with Width, but im talking about the height.
I've tried it tho, but eclipse telling me ' Suspicious size: this will make the view invisible, should be used with layout_weight'

Comment: image is not loading...

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/udhzc.png  thats the url

Comment: try android:weightSum="3 " in parent layout

Comment: doesn't help, setting weightSum"3" and layout_weight="1" at each item. didn't change a thing

Comment: have u changed the parent orientation as vertical?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55767/discussion-between-user3671459-and-asthme).

Answer (score 0):

Use fillviewport= true in scrollview parent layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

      <ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">


            <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/storetest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

            <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/storesingleStore"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

            <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/storesettings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

   </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/storetest1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/storesingleStore2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/storesettings3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```